# Why char parameters promoted to int in parameters?

Tags: c++

I just tried:

```
void p( int x, int y,int a,int b ) {
    printf( "x = 0x%p\ny = 0x%p\na = 0x%p\nb = 0x%p\n", x, y, a, b );
}

int main( ) {
    ( ( void( *)( char, char, char, char, char, char, char, char ) )&p )
        ( 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 );
}
```

Which the expected output from this is:

```
x = 0x01020304
y = 0x05060708
a = 0x???????? <-- random hex value
b = 0x???????? <--
```

Or if the compiler pushing the arguments in reverse:

```
x = 0x????????
y = 0x????????
a = 0x04030201
b = 0x08070605
```

But why the actual output is:

```
x = 0x00000001
y = 0x00000002
a = 0x00000003
b = 0x00000004
```

Is there a limitation? Corrent me if I am wrong here: To get value that is not aligned to 4 bytes, you can just do `8B 45 01` that is `mov eax,ebp+01h` in assembly; there's no problem; if there's another limitation then what is it?

Comment: Obvious UB is obvious.

Comment: Why would the compiler push the arguments rather than just putting them in a register?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Debug mode.

Comment: Not sure why this question is downvoted this much.

Comment: Because you're asking about an implementation detail but you don't say what implementation you're using or what platform you're running on or a thousand other details that affect this. The question is nearly unanswerable.

Comment: @Puppy Starting to understand the situation. None read the last lines; I asked what is the limitation that won't let the compiler make parameter one byte. I didn't ask how it works; it would really help if you could point out why I said it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting a function pointer to a different type and using it to call a function results in undefined behavior.

> From C11 Standard 6.3.2.3 p8:
>
> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another
> type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. *If a converted
> pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type,
> the behavior is undefined.*

The rule is the same in C++:

> A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a different type. The effect of calling
> a function through a pointer to a function type (8.3.5) that is not the same as the type used in the definition
> of the function is undefined

Answer (score 2):

Nasal demons galore. §5.2.10 [expr.reinterpret.cast]/p6:

> A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer
>   of a different type. The effect of calling a function through a
>   pointer to a function type (8.3.5) that is not the same as the type
>   used in the definition of the function is undefined.

Plus, the use of `printf` is *also* undefined behavior (WG14 N1570 §7.21.6.1/p9):

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
>   conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

How function parameters are passed depends on the calling convention. Common x64 calling conventions,
for instance, always pass the first several integer parameters in registers.

Comment: Regardless of numeric or symbolic reference, please do state the standard or draft document referred to.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has undefined behaviour. When you give `printf` the format specifier `%p`, the corresponding variable argument must be of type `void *`, which is not the case in your program.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the C ABI for your platform is specified- they are often specified as including mechanisms like this to cater for variadic arguments, stack alignment, and other such features.

If you want to know why the ABI is that way, you'll have to ask a platform-specific question about the ABI specifically.

Neither the C nor C++ languages have anything to say about this matter whatsoever except that it's totally undefined behaviour. It is totally ABI-specific.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get it since in any case function parameters has alignment of 4.

I tested it in visual studio, and I get the same result. even `#pack(1)` doesn't affect it.

I change your functions to print the variable address:

```
void p( int x, int y,int a,int b ) {
    printf( "x = 0x%p\ny = 0x%p\na = 0x%p\nb = 0x%p\n", &x, &y, &a, &b );
}
```

I got the following result:

```
x = 0x0047F92C
y = 0x0047F930
a = 0x0047F934
b = 0x0047F938
```

As you can see the pointers, as expected, are allign to 4.

now I change the function to get chars:

```
void p( char x, char y,char a,char b ) {
    printf( "x = 0x%p\ny = 0x%p\na = 0x%p\nb = 0x%p\n", &x, &y, &a, &b );
}
```

and the result is:

```
x = 0x0101F750
y = 0x0101F754
a = 0x0101F758
b = 0x0101F75C
```

As you can see it still align to 4!

I think it should answer your question.

Comment: It didn't actually answer my question, but it made me understand better my own question; thanks to this, I made my question clearer.

Comment: What I meant is the arguments has an alignment. that is why char parameter actually takes 4 bytes. is your question is why there is alignment?

Comment: Yes, the others didn't got it right; I deduced that `char` aligned (or promoted to `int`) because calling the same function as if it had `char` parameters didn't made any difference; my question about this was that why there's limitation.

Comment: char parameters are align to 4 for efficiency reasons. if it wasn't aligned access would take more time because you'll need to get the whole 32 bits (in 32 bit OS) and then you'll need to shift it to the lower part and take it. if it is aligned then the shifting part is not needed.

Comment: Aware of it, but as you said `#pack` can't affect it; I think I got what is that limitation, but I will post it later.

Comment: `#pack` affect only on data types like struct or classes. even though compilers can (and some really do) treat function arguments like structs, it not affect function argument. I think the reason is the asm `push` command gets 32 bit argument.

Comment: That's what I thought about.